# Can rm -rf use grep?

Tags: grep, rm

I am trying to use PlayOnLinux to install iTunes but my wine is clogged up, so I want to 100% delete the wine files, so is there any way to delete all files with the tag (or word) wine in them? Perhaps using

`sudo rm -rf`?

Comment: I wouldn't advise this: you never know what folders / files incredibly containing `wine` you could have. And regardless of this, if you installed `wine` through `apt-get`, just `sudo apt-get purge wine`.

Comment: I didn't install through apt-get I installed through .tar.gz @kos

Comment: Ok, still my suggestions would be to go backwards (i.e. if you compiled / installed `wine` in directory X, remove it from directory X). Users configurations files (as well as the "C" drive) are stored in `~/.wine`, removing what you installed manually and `~/.wine` should do. However if you're not sure, `sudo find / -iname '*wine*' 2>/dev/null` and see if something is left, but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command would do it

```
sudo find . -name \*wine\* -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You need ` \ before the * so they aren't globbed. type -f means match files only.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you **NOT** do this, but the answer to your question is:

```
sudo rm -rf *wine*
```

Though I recomend adding v so you can see all that is destroyed.

```
sudo rm -rfv *wine*
```

Comment: What? Do you understand that globbing patterns (in `bash`) work only in the current working directory?

Comment: Nontheless, I'd still not advise this: it's potentially *destructive*.

Comment: That command will work recursively. I tested it in a VM prior to posting the answer.. It made a HUGE mess.. :) I love snapshots. And as I said, I recommend NOT using it.

Comment: No, it won't work recursively (at least not in `bash`); in `zsh` you could so something like `rm -rf **/*wine*`, but, as I said, in `zsh`, not in `bash`. So you either used another shell or this didn't work recursively.

Comment: Anyway, sorry but *why* do you advise this (assuming that it would have worked)? It's like giving someone a gun and tell him *not* to use it to shoot people. I don't get the point.

Comment: @kos is right. I stand corrected I should have paid closer attention to the outcome of my verbose lines. The mask matched a folder I had and it wiped everything in that folder but didn't dive into other folders looking for matches.

Sorry about that.